# URGENT sound of wrinkled audio tape interrupting playback

Tags: sound-design, sound-effects, vintage, tape

Apparently when an audio cassette tape is playing and it is damaged/crinkled/wrinkled at a specific point, this can cause the tape to stop playing with a distinctive crackle or noise.

A director very much wants this sound.  I have never heard it or listened to it, I'm too young to remember tape for one thing.  Please, any advice or examples as soon as possible would be very welcome...I know this forum is less active than it once was, but anyone who sees this, anything you can think of would be so appreciated.

Two things that are NOT close enough:

http://www.f7sound.com/tapedest03.mp3

http://www.pond5.com/sound-effect/26244133/audio-tape-jammed.html

Comment: maybe try this: http://www.sounddogs.com/sound-effects/45/mp3/617416_SOUNDDOGS__a_.mp3   Sounddogs has pretty lowfi previews but I'm sure the full res would sound better

Answer (score 2):

You could record your audio to a cassette tape, wrinkle it, and grab the playback audio.

Nothing beats the real thing ;)

Answer (score 1):

Well, derjur beat me to it as I was going to suggest doing it for real as well!

Cassette players are cheap on eBay, I got one last year for futzing things and it was about £9. Tapes are cheap too as no one wants them anymore!

Comment: destroying a real tape, of course, would allow you to screw up the correct song too

Comment: My problem was partly that it was an effect that had to be able to interrupt the song at any moment.  A "called cue" in a theatrical production.  So destroying the song on tape at the right moment was not an option.  The budget and schedule of this project didn't give me a spare second to work with the real equipment.  I will invest in a cassette player for future projects when I get a little more forewarning with the request!  Solution? Scotch tape wrinkled, warped down in pitched and futzed all with Ableton's built-in erosion and dynamic tube effects.

Comment: I do like your way though